# Go integration with Protocol Buffers?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

After a quick look at the documentation, I immediately started to think about integration with existing languages and applications and was wondering whether support would be provided for Protocol Buffers?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/goprotobuf/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They will be fully supported in the next release. Read their [FAQ in docs](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc#baM9oaU8D4s/doc/go_faq.html&q=protocol.*buffer%20package:http://go%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=124)

Comment: All I can say is... yay! This is going to enable some amazingly quick and powerful stuff to be built!

Answer (score 6):

Ok, this is an old question. But since I ended up here with the same question and found a more up to date answer, let me post what I found:

http://code.google.com/p/goprotobuf/

Answer (score 1):

I'd be *very* surprised if there didn't exist a Protocol Buffers library for Go already internally. (I don't know for sure, and I'm not going to check as then it would be confidential :)

However, it's quite possible that it's a proto1 library rather than the open-sourced proto2.

I'm sure someone somewhere will port proto2 to Go, whether that's someone internal or external.

Comment: Rob Pike confirmed that there is at least one working implementation internally that should be released shortly, and that they are working on a new more high performance oriented version too.

Answer (score 0):

Protocol buffers are now fully supported in Go.  The official Go library can be found at [github.com/golang/protobuf](https://github.com/golang/protobuf).